# What is protected method access level with regard to accessing from another object

Tags: java

I'm passing an object reference to a Util class. I'm attempting to invoke a protected method on the Util class but I getting a compile time error -

```
The method setPositionChild(Field, int, int) from the type Manager is not visible
```

To invoke a protected method is it required to be in the implementing class only ? Can I not pass the reference to an external class and invoke the reference from there ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protected method can be accessed from subclasses. Make that method public if you want to access from any class. See details [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2)

Also as mentioned by @Sean Patrick Floyd, from classes in the same package!

Comment: And from classes in the same package!

Comment: "Protected method can be accessed from subclasses." should this not be "Protected method can be accessed from subclass implementation" since the compile time error is thrown when I pass the reference of the subclass to an external class and invoke the method from that external class ?

Comment: @user470184 You can't access a protected method of an instance unless you are trying to access it from (a) somewhere in it's subclass, or (b) in a class that sits in the same package. Having an instance of an object does not allow you to access it's protected method. What I understand from your description is you require to make that method public.